# What is the proper way to ignore an error for a statement with no returned value?

Tags: error-handling, rust

If you have a line of code that can fail without affecting the program in a significant way, what is the proper way to ignore it?

I can simply exclude `.expect("")` But, I believe that will cause a crash if it does fail, correct?

I can use `unwrap_or_default()` where implemented.

I can obviously use a `match`, or `if let` statement, but there is no code to run as a follow-up, so these feel wrong.

Is there a proper or idiomatic way to handle these situations?

Comment: If you don't care about either the `Ok` or `Err` variant of the `Result`, you are simply ignoring the return value of the function. The idiomatic way of doing that without incurring a warning from the complier is: `let _ = <expression returning Result>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the result, assign it to `_`:

```
fn foo() -> Result<i32, String> {
    Err(String::from("This is an error"))
}

fn main() {
    let _ = foo();
}
```

If you do care about the result, you can use `if let`:

```
fn main() {
    if let Ok(x) = foo() {
        dbg!(x);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `.and_then()` or `.map()` on the result:

```
fn main() {
    let _ = foo().map(|x| dbg!(x));
}
```

The downside is that this uses a closure, so you can't return from the outer function in there.

Comment: As of Rust 1.59, you can omit the `let` and just write `_ = foo();` in order to ignore the result of `foo()`. See https://twitter.com/davidtolnay/status/1564729670779604993, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1590-2022-02-24 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/79016